# undefined method 'article' - use data from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are articles and comments.

```
article has_many :comments
comment belongs_to :article
```

I want to get all comments where value_id is equal to value_id attribute in the article that comment belongs_to.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :article

  def self.value_comments
    where(value_id: self.article.value_id)
  end

end
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `article' for #<Class:0x007fd2a7e46d18>
```

controller

```
@value_comments = Comment.value_comments.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Having read your question again, my understanding is that you want to find all `Comments` whose `value_id` matches the `value_id` of their associated `Article`.

Your code is nearly correct - you need a few more parts to get this to work. You need to join your `Comment` table to your `Article` table using [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins). Then, refer to the column in a where function using [`arel_table`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/ClassMethods/arel_table).

So you should end up with something like this:

```
def self.value_comments
  joins(:article).where(self.arel_table[:value_id].eq Article.arel_table[:value_id])
end
```

You could also consider using [sexy_scopes](https://github.com/samleb/sexy_scopes) to make it easier to access your columns.

Comment: But, as I stated, I don't want to use it on a specific Comment. 
I want to get all comments that fulfill certain condition where(value_id: article.value_id). 
Do you understand what I mean? It's similar to getting all comments where(published: true)

Comment: Do you mean you want to get Comments that match a specific, single id or Comments that match the value_id of whatever their associated Article is?